# Finding $-8$ in $\Bbb Z \pmod 5$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

This is a very simple question but what is $-8$ in $\Bbb Z \pmod 5$?  I am looking for a positive number. I know $5 \times 2 = 10$ so it is either $2$ or $-3$.  I assume I am just looking at it a little confused because of the negative value.

Comment: Well if you are looking for a positive number, it can't be -3, can it? :)

Comment: Lmao I would assume so haha

Answer (score 1):

$$-8 = 5\cdot (-2) + 2$$

The answer is 2

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways, e.g.

$(1)\ \ \ {-}8 \equiv -8+5+5\equiv 2$

$(2)\ \ \  {-}8 \equiv -4 -4 \equiv 1 + 1$

$(3)\ \ \ {-}8 \equiv  8(-1)\equiv 3(-1)\equiv 2$

Answer (score 0):

Just keep adding or subtracting $5$ until you get the appropriate value:

$$-8 + 5 = -3 \\
-3 + 5 = 2.$$